# Get value of variable named in a string

Tags: realbasic, xojo, realstudio

Is there any way to get the value of a variable that has been named in a string.
For instance:

```
Dim number As Integer = 12

Dim numberCopy As Integer = Convert("number")
' numberCopy will now equal 12
' Convert is the function to convert the string to the variable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like that can be done only with Introspection, and only if the variable holding the value is a property of a class. Your example, where the variable is only temporarily known inside a function, cannot be made work as you like.

To learn more about Introspection, see the documentation and examples of the same name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wasn't sure if Introspection could access native types. I also realised the flaw in my plan after I posted the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a Dictionary instead of straight properties and variables.

For instance

```
   dim d as new dictionary
   d.value("number") = 12
```

Then when you need the value, you can do

```
   Dim numberCopy As Integer = d.value("number")
```

Nice thing about Dictionary is since keys as well as values are variant, you can throw at it pretty much anything, all variable types, as well as objects.

See [Language Reference](http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/dictionary)